# Outlook Unusual sign-in activity

Tags: microsoft-outlook, phishing

I've had a bit of a weird experience with my Outlook account and am not sure what to think of it.

At 02:42 this morning I received an email from the  Microsoft Account Team (account-security-noreply@account.microsoft.com) saying there was some unusual activity on my account, coming from the following source:

```
Country/region: Unknown
IP-address: 25.160.32.24
Date: 22-11-2016 02:42 (CET)
```

I quickly verified whether this was not a phishing email, but in my Outlook inbox the email is marked as "This message is from a trusted sender" in a green banner.

When I geo locate the IP, I get the following ISP: **UK Ministry of Defence**

I didn't use the links in the email, but logged in via the web browser to change my password. I checked for other anomalies in my recent activity log, but to my surprise, this sign-in is not in the recent activity. Then when I returned to my inbox this warning email is suddenly in trash.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Seems like other people had this same problem. `Basically companies run out of private addresses and are re-using large public address blocks already assigned to government agencies that either aren't being used or are not announced.` So... no, this is not a government 's secret agent spying on your shopping list.  :) The mail is legit so do set a strong password/account and make sure your PC is secured.

Comment: I have received an email like this each morning for the last three days. I've changed my password everyday since then.